# MKRoute Not Identifying Ferry Routes

Tags: swift, mapkit, core-location

Within `MKDirections` I am looking for a route that does not comprise any step with a ferry in it. Using the `MKDirectionsTransportType` at this stage isn't helpful as the ferry can be a single step in an overall route that would not be identified at an overall route level. As a result I am looking at the transport type for each step `MKRoute.Step`. However, it does not look like Apple is properly reporting a step that is clearly a ferry as a transport type that is not an automobile. Printing out instructions for each step I get the following for a given step: *"Take the “Washington State Ferry” ferry"* Clearly this step is using something other than an automobile and from the list of transport type options I would have assumed `transit` but again it's actually returning `automobile`.

Has anyone dealt with this prior and is there another reliable way to be able to detect and eliminate something like a ferry? I am hesitant to use the string and simply search for "ferry" as that could be inconsistent and might be the name of a legitimate road, etc. Not clear why Apple is not identifying a ferry properly which is also happening with other ferries - the Long Island Ferry - as an example.

Comment: "Clearly this step is using something other than an automobile" I don't agree. The automobile is on the ferry. What's different is the surface under the automobile's tires: a ferry rather than a road. But it's still an automobile trip.

Comment: The definition says "This property reflects the transport type employed by the step". The transport type of the step is a ferry not a stationary automobile. It is fair to say the overall trip is for an automobile but this is a specific step. There are other trips where segments aren't listed as automobile.